# How to make this shortcode work for post content wordpress

Tags: shortcode

I have been trying but its not working.

but if i try

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[mimo]"); ?> <?php echo do_shortcode("[mibaby]"); ?>
```

it will work fine.

But to apply it in post content using `[mimo] [mibaby]`

it won't work.

Here is the Functions i am using...

```
function wpb_custom_new_menuw() {
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
add_shortcode('mibaby', 'wpb_custom_new_menuw');



function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
add_shortcode('mimo', 'wpb_custom_new_menu');
```

I AM TRYING TO disable/remove wpautop on a single post using shortcode

Answer (score 1):

This will not work in the post content context because filter for **wpauto** is executed before the shortcodes are processed. So, your shortcode tries to disable **wpauto** filter, but that filter was already executed on that content.

You can do with this (in theme functions.php file, and similar for excerpt):

```
add_action('the_content', 'wse_281097_content_remove_wpautop', 1);
function wse_281097_content_remove_wpautop() {
    if (is_single(15)) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}
```

This will remove **wpauto** early by checking if the current post is with ID 15, so it will disable **wpauto** for that post only. You can replace condition in line 3 with anything you want to target your specific posts.